# Remove White space before and after a special character and join them python

Tags: python, regex

```
My_string =  My Awesome Company billing @ example . com Contractor Invoice # 000015 Acme Projects - Taxable Product Contractor Invoice Summary Account Information Don Test don @ example . com Contractor Invoice Date : 10 / 26 / 2016 Amount Due $ 21 .


Desired_string = My Awesome Company billing@example.com Contractor Invoice#000015 Acme Projects-Taxable Product Contractor Invoice Summary Account Information Don Test don@example.com Contractor Invoice Date:10/26/2016 Amount Due$21.
```

In simple words I need to remove space from before and after a special character. Also can you share a good source to learn regex from

```
with open('sentence.txt') as txtfile:
string = str(txtfile.read())
list_of_str = string.split()
new_list = []
for d in range(len(list_of_str)):
    if not (list_of_str[d].isalpha() or list_of_str[d].isalnum()):
       print(list_of_str[d-1], list_of_str[d:])
       new_list.append(str(list_of_str[d-1]) + str(list_of_str[d]) + str(list_of_str[d+1]))
    else:
        new_list.append(list_of_str[d])
print(new_list)

Output: ['Onlineï»¿MyAwesome', 'Awesome', 'Company', 'billing', 'billing@example', 'example', 'example.com', 'com', 'Contractor', 'Invoice', 'Invoice#000015', '000015', 'Acme', 'Projects', 'Projects-Taxable', 'Taxable', 'Product', 'Contractor', 'Invoice', 'Summary', 'Account', 'Information', 'Don', 'Test', 'don', 'don@example', 'example', 'example.com', 'com', 'Contractor', 'Invoice', 'Date', 'Date:10', '10', '10/26', '26', '26/2016', '2016', 'Amount', 'Due', 'Due$21', '21']
```

At first i tried to use this but I think regex can help

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: A good place to experiment with regex is [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily solve  this problem using regex, rather than you current code.

You can use this regex,

`([@.#$\/:-]) ?` (Space followed by character set having special chars followed by an optional space. You can add more characters in the set as per your needs.)

This regex captures a space followed by one character in your character set followed by optional space and replaces it with the character it captured in group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCIVmk/1)

Sample python codes,

```
import re
s = 'My Awesome Company billing @ example . com Contractor Invoice # 000015 Acme Projects - Taxable Product Contractor Invoice Summary Account Information Don Test don @ example . com Contractor Invoice Date : 10 / 26 / 2016 Amount Due $ 21 .'
s = re.sub(' ([@.#$\/:-]) ?',r'\1', s)
print(s)
```

which gives following output,

```
My Awesome Company billing@example.com Contractor Invoice#000015 Acme Projects-Taxable Product Contractor Invoice Summary Account Information Don Test don@example.com Contractor Invoice Date:10/26/2016 Amount Due$21.
```

Let me know if this works fine for you.

Comment: Thanks although the output i got was "My Awesome Company billingexamplecom Contractor Invoice000015 Acme ProjectsTaxable Product Contractor Invoice Summary Account Information Don Test donexamplecom Contractor Invoice Date10262016 Amount Due21"

Comment: I got the desired output by using s = re.sub(' ([@.#$\/:-]) ?',r'\1', s). How can i learn regex can you share some good resource?

Comment: @SaranjitSaikia: You can find many on net but I loved this one alot. [Regex Tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) And you should use https://regex101.com for testing/debugging. There are many others too and as you will stay in touch on SO, you will get to know more such. I too learned most of the stuff from here only.

Comment: And for regex replacement part, yes I should have escaped backslash and written `\\1` instead of `\1` or as raw strings you could write `r'\1'` which you already did so great job :)